# Any Faceted Search UI Libraries for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, elasticsearch

I don't want to develop a custom faceted search component(s) in my application, so I'm searching for an open-source & free **faceted** search UI library for Angular. I had previously found Searchkit or Elastic UI to integrate faceted search into my React projects. These libraries seem to have some compatibility with Angular, but it seems to me (I might be wrong) that you have to create the view yourself if you use Angular or you have to introduce React into your project to be able to use the JSX tags.

By faceted search, I mean that there is some sort of side bar/panel which can filter results like products, by categories such as brands, ratings, price, etc. The typical filters you see on the left side of the window, when you shop at Amazon, Walmart, etc.

Are there any reputable open-source & free faceted search UI libraries for Angular to integrate with locally hosted search backend like ElasticSearch, Solr, etc. which do not require you to integrate React into your Angular project and/or develop your own view components? I would also like to avoid managed search services like Algolia, etc. Can you please provide examples in code of your recommendations and feedback on the pros/cons. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Note that questions asking for recommendations of libraries and components are specifically off-topic.

Comment: Holy hell, did you find something ? Because I am searching for the exact same thing right now :)